# is bleeping computer a safe website to ask for virus removal?

Tags: virus-removal, forum

I was lurking to this section http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/f/22/virus-trojan-spyware-and-malware-removal-logs/ and they always ask you to install something but users there seem to solve their problem with no issues. I am worried that they might install another malicious program in one of their links.

I am trying to clean my computer but before i post there i just want to ask some approval from you guys.

Comment: Take any website like this with a grain of salt.  Follow their advice if it makes sense.

Comment: For what it's worth, I got some great help from the folks there to remove some truculent malware from a friend's laptop.

Answer (score 3):

I have used [AdwCleaner](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/) from Bleeping Computer and it is a truly excellent piece of software, that has gotten rid of toolbar addons (such as the Babylon toolbar) that other software had failed to remove.

If that is testament to Bleeping Computer's software then you should have no worries.

Comment: Seconded; I can further give Bleeping Computer's [ComboFix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/) tool an excellent report, having successfully used it many times, in my former professional capacity as an IT support specialist, to get malware off machines so thoroughly pestiferated that nothing else would even install, much less actually work.

Comment: @AaronMiller AdwCleaner not only removed nasties from my PC, but did it blisteringly fast too. I'll checkout ComboFix :)

Comment: If AdwCleaner can't get rid of it, ComboFix will. If ComboFix can't get rid of it, it's time to repave the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the tools on sites like this are information gathering tools, looking for installed applications, running applications and weird startup items.

This is generally for identification of the malware or problem, and then the forum users generally recommend third party tools to fix the identified problem. Many forums use this approach.

That said, BleepingComputer is reputable enough, but the advice is given by individuals. Be mindful that someone could always have a bad recommendation or have mal-intent.